# passing values to another php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to pass values from one page to another page.

```
    <form action="../PHP/sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email<?= $row['vacancyid'];?>" value='<?= $row['email'];?>'>
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Apply Now" id="btn<?= $row['vacancyid']?>" name="btn<?= $row['vacancyid']?>">
      </td>
    <tr>
      <?php
      }
     ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

sendmail.php

```
    <?php
    $email2 = $_POST['email'];
    ?>
```

i eant to know get name="email to sendemail.php page.
thank you

Comment: Change `name="email<?= $row['vacancyid'];?>"` to `name="email"`

Comment: where is your button. do from over check syntax etc.

Comment: @AhmedGinani i eddited the code again

Comment: you want to pass multiple email ?

Comment: @Deckerz iwant to pass the name="email<?= $row['vacancyid'];?> to sendemail.php page.other wise all emails send to same email address

Comment: @AhmedGinani yeah friend.i want to send emails to various email adresses. when i use only name="email" e mails are send same email address.

Comment: You should use an array in your html: `name="email[]"`. Then `$_POST['email']` will be an array containing all the addresses.

Comment: @jeroen i want to send one email in one time.

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: i want to do send one email one time which is contained value='<?= $row['email'];?>'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use name as a array:

```
  <form action="../PHP/sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
               <input type="text" id="email" name="email[]" value="<?= $row['email'];?>">
          </td>  
        </tr>
          <?php
          }
         ?>
      <tr>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Apply Now" id="btn" name="btn">
      </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

php file:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
print_r($email);
?>
```

Comment: ..sorry for previous informayion.i want to send one email in one time.when i use name="email" every emil goes to same email address.